# Styling radio button - not work in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, radio-button

I have tried to make own style of radio button. Everything works well in Chrome, but in IE and Firefox there are still some display errors.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id ="light" name="choice" value="none""><label for="light">Light me</label>
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png') center center no-repeat;
background-size: 2em;
width: 2em;
height: 2em;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

What is wrong?

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: I would advise that you don't so this. It can be a bit of a usability issue.

Comment: You can add Safari to the list of the browsers in which that example does not work ;)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "some display errors"?

Comment: Some form elements just can't be styled with reliable consistency across browsers

Comment: I would suggest you that you use some jquery plugin for that. See this:

http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/4yVka/2/)

What you need to do is hide the radio button and only use the label for toggling it.  So, I set `input[type="radio"]` to `display:none`, and moved some of the CSS to the `label` selector or a new selector for the button, to which I gave the class 'button':

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id ="light" name="choice" value="none"">
<label for="light">
<span class="button"></span>
Light me
</label>​​​
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
.button {   background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    float:left;
}
label { 
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height:32px;
}
​
```

Here's a good walk through of stylizing inputs with CSS: http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/

Comment: The problem about hiding input elements is that they lose their keyboard navigation ability. And that's sad.

Comment: The other problem I've found is some browsers will not show an alert for required hidden elements.