# How do I change radio button border color for firefox?

Tags: html, css

I am facing some issue in changing the border color from radio button in firefox.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type='radio'] {
   -moz-appearance: none;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #ccc insert;
   width:20px;
   height:20px
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYqx/4859/)

I wanted to remove the highlighted top left dark border from the radio button. Is there any solution to remove that border only using `CSS`

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613933/styling-radio-button-not-work-in-ie-and-firefox#13614105 ?

Comment: Replace inset to insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a label around it and style that.

Here is a link with some examples

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953