# How to change the style of radio button in FireFox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I try to change the radio button, I try the following line. My style apples in All browsers but **Firefox**.  In fact, *I don't see the style in Firefox.*

```css
#payment_method_paypal[type='radio']::after {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -6px !important;
    left: -1px !important;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid #776330 !important;
}

#payment_method_paypal[type='radio']:checked::after {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -6px !important;
    left: -1px !important;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #776330 !important;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid #776330 !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff !important;
    margin-left: 6px;
}


#payment_method_stripe[type='radio']::after {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -6px !important;
    left: -1px !important;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid #776330 !important;
}

#payment_method_stripe[type='radio']:checked::after {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -6px !important;
    left: -1px !important;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #776330 !important;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid #776330 !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff !important;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<input id="payment_method_stripe" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="stripe" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">
<label for="payment_method_stripe">Credit / Debit Card</label>

<input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" data-order_button_text="Proceed to PayPal">
<label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rabiei/9mvzyh4q/6/)

How to apply this style in **firefox**?
What is the problem that cause not showing in **Firefox**?

I have already tried the following solution:

[Styling radio button - not work in IE and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613933/styling-radio-button-not-work-in-ie-and-firefox)
[How to change style of radio and checkbox input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793716/how-to-change-style-of-radio-and-checkbox-input)

Comment: A pseudo element generated by `::after` is supposed to be pretty much the same, as if it was an actual child element. But - input elements are _empty_ elements, they can not have children. So Firefox is actually behaving rather logically correct here, while the other browsers are not.

Comment: [Can I use a :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669/1427878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Sato's answer, but you could also add this to your CSS:

```
input[type='radio'] {
  -moz-appearance: initial !important;
}
```

I'd try to avoid using `!important` in your CSS, it's not a good practice to use. I think if you remove it from your code, you could probably remove it from my snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will work for you.

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.checkbox input {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.checkbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid #776330;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.checkbox span::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #776330;
    display: none;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ span::after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox" for="payment_method_stripe">
  <input id="payment_method_stripe" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="stripe" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">
  <span></span>
  Credit / Debit Card
</label>


<label class="checkbox" for="payment_method_paypal">
  <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal" data-order_button_text="Proceed to PayPal">
  <span></span>
  PayPal
</label>
```

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  accent-color: red;
}
```